# Use MEF to allow only 2 instances at max per application

Tags: c#-4.0, inversion-of-control, mef

I am using MEF as an IOC in my application. I found myself stuck in a situation where I need exactly two instance at a time for a class in my application (across all threads). I thought it would be easy just by adding export attribute twice with different container name and then using that container name to create two instances.

```
[Export("Condition-1",typeof(MyClass)]
[Export("Condition-2",typeof(MyClass)]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class MyClass  {   }
```

And then export them as

```
Container.GetExport<MyClass>("Condition-1").Value
Container.GetExport<MyClass>("Condition-2").Value
```

But this trick did not work. I finally able to solve my problem by using CompsositionBatch

```
cb.AddExportedValue<MyClass>("Condition-1",new MyClass());
cb.AddExportedValue<MyClass>("Condition-2",new MyClass());
```

But my question is, Why am I not able to get different instances on the basis of Contract Name. Is it right that Contract name does not matter if CreationPolicy is shared?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the setup of `PartCreationPolicyAttribute` that decorates `MyClass`.

CreationPolicy.Shared means that a single instance will be returned for each call to `Container.GetExport`. It is like a singleton. What you need in your case is the CreationPolicy.NonShared policy which will return a different instance for each clla to `Container.GetExport`.

Here's a good article on [Part Creation Policy](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/01/09/mef-for-beginner-part-creation-policy-part-6.aspx).
Also have a look at [ExportFactory in MEF 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/17/exportfactory-amp-lt-t-amp-gt-in-mef-2-alok.aspx?Redirected=true) for MEF2 additions regarding the lifetime and sharing of parts

Comment: I don't want NonShared. I want semi shared. Means I want a shared instance if imported with contract name "Condition-1" and another shared instance if imported with contract name "Condition-2". I want a shared instance attached to contract name and not to class type. Thats why I was decorating the class with two export attributes.